# I needed grouped Stacked Bar chart in compate current and previous years data with category wise count display in chart

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js, bar-chart, stacked

**I would like the chart as shown in below image in Jquery, I have tried lots of code but unable to achive it, I can post the code which i have tried but its worth less.**

In the chart we are trying to compare the sold business by category wise for last two yers.

Please note we need chart as shown in below picture,**
[image]

Appologies for not sharing the code. (tried solution link:https://dojo.telerik.com/igUmaqOw/3 in here i have try with kendo but i would love to do in jquery)

Comment: I need same chart but slightly different, I will wait for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi mate,
Here I have Created the chart with kendoChart, Hope you will like it.**

Here in snippet we need licence but you can use the below link,
Kendo Editor : https://dojo.telerik.com/AkUrAnon/3

Chart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.default-ocean-blue.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Practice Versoon"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Auto",
                    stack: "2021",
                    data: [1, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
                }, {
                    name: "Silver Medals",
                    stack: "2021",
                    data: [19, 25, 21, 26, 28, 31, 35, 60, 31, 34, 32, 24, 40, 38, 29],
                },{
                    name: "Auto",
                    stack: "2021",
                    data: [10, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
                },
                 {
                    name: "Auto",
                    stack: "2020",
                    data: [1, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
                }, {
                    name: "Silver Medals",
                    stack: "2020",
                    data: [19, 25, 21, 26, 28, 31, 35, 60, 31, 34, 32, 24, 40, 38, 29],
                },{
                    name: "Gold Medals",
                    stack: "2020",
                    data: [10, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                    
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```